# Android w/ Java: Using Seekbar to adjust volume

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android App development (on android studio) and to start off I'm creating a simple 'bonk' soundboard app, and testing it using the Pixel 2 android emulator. The goal of the app is to play the bonk noise whenever someone presses the BONK button on my main screen. I also wanted to implement a seekbar that adjusts the volume when you slide it. To do this I followed a simple implementation I found here on StackOverflow (shown below). 
Even though the rest of my app works fine, for some reason my volume won't adjust whenever I slide the seekbar. Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.bonk;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button bonkButton;
    SeekBar volumeSeekBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bonkButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bonkButton);
        volumeSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volumeSeekBar);

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bonksound);
        bonkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Volumizer.java**

```
package com.example.bonk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class Volumizer extends Activity {
    //Called when the activity is first created.
    private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls() {
        try {
            volumeSeekbar = findViewById(R.id.volumeSeekBar);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bonkButton"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="232dp"
        android:text="@string/bonk"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/volumeSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas as of what I may be doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Hi John. Have you set a break point in onProgressChanged? Does it try to set the volume? Code looks okay overall. It even handles the max volume correctly which is good.

Comment: Instead of passing 0 as the 3rd argument in setStreamVolume, maybe you can temporarily pass:  AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND to see if it is working.

Comment: Also from the setStreamVolume docs, "This method has no effect if the device implements a fixed volume policy as indicated by isVolumeFixed()". It would be good to eliminate this as a cause also.

Comment: @Elletlar: thanks for the comment, I passed 'AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND' but unfortunately the sound doesn't play whenever I change the seekerbar

Comment: @Elletlar: I think that means that my app isn't calling this class when it starts, or at least it definitively doesn't get to onProgressChanged()

Comment: In Android Studio, click to the left of audioManager.setStreamVolume. It should make a red dot which represents a break-point then select 'Run -> Debug -> Your App'. It should now stop at any breakpoints that you set.

Comment: You can also add this to your initControls method: 'Log.d("Tag", "Is volume fixed?: " + audioManager.isVolumeFixed());' to test whether your device allows the volume to be altered. The output should appear in the "logcat" tab at the bottom of Android Studio.

Comment: @Elletlar: Thanks for the tips, after running through the program with the debugger tool I've figured out for sure that my program isn't calling the Volumizer class at all, even when the app first launches. Do you think there's something missing that I should change in my main class?

Comment: Without knowing more, I would probably move all the Volumizer code into the MainActivity. I don't see any need for the playout and the volume change to be in separate activities. But if you want to persist with 2 activities, you will need to call startActivity on the Volumizer.

Comment: @Elletlar: Yeah, moving it to main ended up solving the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Great. Glad it is working. Can you put your solution in the answer. It will help people in the future if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by moving my initControls() function definition into my MainActivity.java class and calling it onCreate.